# Python subprocess gives syntax error but runs from shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a shell command from python, and getting syntax errors. It is probably related to the fact that there are nested quotes, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Here is the command:

```
In [44]: command
Out[44]: '/Applications/itt/idl/bin/idl -e "print, barycorr(2456718.886512, 16.109814, -36.799472, 0, obsname=\'CTIO\')"'

In [45]: print command
/Applications/itt/idl/bin/idl -e "print, barycorr(2456718.886512, 16.109814, -36.799472, 0, obsname='CTIO')"
```

When I run the command using either of the two below, I get a syntax error in idl:

```
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

If I run the command (output of [45]) from the command line, it works perfectly. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct your list manually, eg.:

```
cmd_lst = ['/Applications/itt/idl/bin/idl',
           '-e',
           ("print, barycorr(2456718.886512, 16.109814, -36.799472, 0,"
            " obsname='CTIO')"),
           ]

subprocess.call(cmd_lst)
```

I splitted the long string into two lines. The parenthesis makes sure it's handled as the same string even if spanning over multiple lines. As a side-effect the escapes for the single quotes may be omitted if not needed by the called program.

Comment: this is exactly what shlex is doing, also running with shell=True means you don't need to split the commands

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That's right. But because of the additional fork with all the overhead (+evtl. security risks for unchecked shell commands) i wouldn't default to it. Manually constructing the list allows one to actually understand/see what's happening behind the scene without an additional layer of obscurity, which i thought useful in an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Don, that worked. I think splitting the long string is what made the difference, since I didn't need to escape the quotes.